# Github permission denied while cloning a repository

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git, clone, github

[image: Permission denied]

I am learning github and I started today .At first everything went fine and I was able to clone a repository then commit and push changes but now the second repository is not working I am not able to clone it from github and also not able to create a project in my system and push it.(It's a public repository)

Comment: This a public or private repository?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

You might need to run it as root or use [sudo](/questions/tagged/sudo) to escalate your privileges to root level.
Also make sure the GitHub repository exists.